# Inserting multiple image problem

Tags: graphics, floats

I am trying to add images with caption i.e. they are 23 in total . the funny thing is up to 5 shows then it disappears .

```
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{q1}
 \caption{Question 1 :Job Position}

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{q2}\\
 \caption{Question 1 :Experience Process Management}

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{q3}
 \caption{Question 1 :Experience Process Management}

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{q4}\\
 \caption{Question 1 :Experience Process Management}

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{q5}
 \caption{Question 1 :Experience Process Management}

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{q7}\\
 \caption{Question 1 :Experience Procss Management}

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{q8}
 \caption{Question 1 :Experience Process Management}

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{q9}\\
 \caption{Question 1 :Experience Process Management}
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
\end{figure}
```

what am i doing wrong ? or better yet what should i do

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) One option is to simply break the single large float (`figure` environment) into multiple smaller ones. Floats cannot break across pages, so you only see the few that fit onto one page.

Comment: normally you have _one_ image per `figure` environment. Also delete all the `\\ ` which are not required here.

Answer (score 1):

The `figure` environment will not break across pages; what your example code is giving you is one, massively overfull page. If you examine the log file, you'll be certain to find a reference to a rather overfull page.

Instead of using a `figure` environment, I suggest you load the `caption` package and replace all `\caption{...}` statements with `\captionof{figure}{...}` statements. Use `\noindent` to make sure that there's no paragraph indentation affecting the placement of the image files, and use `\bigskip` (or `\medskip`, if you prefer) to create a bit of separation between the captions and the following images.

The following screenshot shows the first page produced by the example shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}


\noindent
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{q1}
\captionof{figure}{Question 1 :Job Position}

\bigskip\noindent
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{q2}
\captionof{figure}{Question 1 :Experience Process Management}

\bigskip\noindent
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{q3}
\captionof{figure}{Question 1 :Experience Process Management}

\bigskip\noindent
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{q4}
\captionof{figure}{Question 1 :Experience Process Management}

\bigskip\noindent
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{q5}
\captionof{figure}{Question 1 :Experience Process Management}

\bigskip\noindent
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{q7}
\captionof{figure}{Question 1 :Experience Procss Management}

\bigskip\noindent
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{q8}
\captionof{figure}{Question 1 :Experience Process Management}

\bigskip\noindent
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{q9}
\captionof{figure}{Question 1 :Experience Process Management}


\bigskip\noindent
etc.\ etc.

\end{document}
```